# Bootstrap icon-bar not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

the icon-bar in the navbar menu of Bootstrap not showing when resizing the browser:

http://jsbin.com/ixAqinA/1/

```
   <section class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="/">
        brand
      </a>
    </div>
    </section>
```

you can see the JSBin example live: http://jsbin.com/ixAqinA/1/

Comment: What do you mean by add icon class "Explain please"

Comment: Yup, i tried that but still not working, you can test it in the example!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to wrap it inside

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"></nav>
```

- Your code corrected: http://jsbin.com/ixAqinA/5/
- [Example from Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default)

Comment: Sorry, it's just a matter of eyes: the icon-bar is there actually, but it's colored with white like the background, so i can't see it

anyway, your answer solve the problem too, thak you

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue, but this solution did not work for me because of changes in Bootstrap.

For Bootstrap 3.1.1, I needed the following style to show the icon bars on a custom colored navbar that is fixed to the top (so .navbar-default doesn't work)

```
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar{ background-color: #fff;}
```

Just change #fff for the color you would like to show.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 4 doesn't use `.icon-bar` any more.
There it has to be done like:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

For more details you should look [here](https://github.com/iamphill/Bootstrap-Offcanvas/issues/30) or in the [documentation of Bootstrap 4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/)