# span.icon-bar not being displayed in the browser

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, icons, navigationbar

I am trying to use the Bootstrap class="icon-bar" but its not showing up on the screen.
The elements are present in the screen but default height and width is showing up 0.

I have been through multiple questions on Stack Overflow and different sites but no help.

Following is the code:

```
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top bg-light">
        <div class="containter">
            <button type="button" class ="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                   <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
   </nav>
</body>
```

Image:
[image: span.icon-var invisible]

Links that I have followed:

[Bootstrap icon-bar span not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45115371/bootstrap-icon-bar-span-not-visible)

[Bootstrap icon-bar not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206741/bootstrap-icon-bar-not-showing)

[Bootstap:span class icon bar not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46122964/bootstapspan-class-icon-bar-not-working)

Comment: There is no `icon-bar` class defined in bootstrap 4. Please refer to current versions documentation. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navbar/

Comment: Thank you so much. I am really very stupid. I was thinking that all the Bootstrap 3 attributes would be consumable in Bootstrap 4 as well. Thanks a lot again sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered in the comments by @Akhi, there is no span.icon-bar in Bootstrap 4.

Instead we need to use the class: `<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>`

Doing so has resolved my problem.